# position radio buttons elements over background image

Tags: html, css, radio-button, background-image

I have a backgorund image and want to position some radio buttons (the circle of the radio button will be hidden and only the label will appear) just close to the red triangles (as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUTm6.png)) .
 How can I do this? Please see my code here

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUTm6.png" alt="Synoptic table" align="center">
<div class="buton">
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="a" id="a" />
  <label for="a">text radio 1</label>
</div>
<div class="buton">
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="b" id="b" />
  <label for="b">text radio 2</label>
</div>
<div class="buton">
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="c" id="c" />
  <label for="c">text radio 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing platform. It's up to you to provide a code example. We can help you with your approach!

Comment: `position:absolute` of `fixed` - thats about as much as anyone can help until you show us more code

Comment: please insert your code into your question, properly formatted e.g. as a snippet

Comment: @Andreas - I updated the question

Comment: Ok, I edited the question for you and converted your code to a snippet

Comment: where should i put the jijia.png so when pressing the button "Run code snippet" that png to be visible? Now seems is a broken image.

Comment: You can upload it in your question, then you see the image link.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to solve that.
I put the position as a style in the div that includes the radio button

```
<div class="buton" style="position:absolute; left:400px; top:250px">
  <input type="radio" name="a" value="b" id="b" /> <label for="b"> radio text 2 </label>
</div>
```